# How to use clang::Stmt in the headers of llvm, like 'IRBuilder.h'

Tags: clang, llvm

I need to use the class `clang::Stmt` in the header `IRBuilder.h` of llvm. But when I make the project, the llvm project can not find the headers of clang. 
I added this line into `IRBuilder.h`: 
`#include "clang/AST/Stmt.h"`
But the make error said it can not find this header file.
How can I write the path to Stmt.h, so that I can inlcude a clang's header in a llvm's file ?

Comment: LLVM is a dependency of clang, not the other way around. Are you sure you need to refer to clang internals in an LLVM header? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep a map<Value*, Stmt*> to record which AST node does an IR come from.

Comment: That change would belong somewhere in clang's CodeGen, not IRBuilder.

Comment: I need to insert the map in the method `IRBuilder.Insert()`. In `CodeGen` also need do something to get the `Stmt` being parsed.

Comment: I would definitely not do it this way. Like I said, LLVM does not depend on clang, and adding a dependency just for this feels wrong. Have you considered modifying [the `InsertHelper` method in `CodeGenFunction`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CodeGenFunction_8cpp_source.html#l01835)? It's called for every instruction inserted, and would not require any changes in LLVM.

Comment: More generally, `IRBuilder` takes an `Inserter` as a template parameter, which lets you invoke a callback for every instruction inserted, without having to change `IRBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I find their are two `InsertHelper`.One belongs to `CGBuilderInserter`, the other one belongs to `CodeGenFunction`. Do I just record in the  `CodeGenFunction`'s one ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I implemented it under your guide !! Thank you !

Comment: Excuse me. Now I want to use the map in my pass. But it seems the passes can not get the clang's header? How can I use the `map<Value*, Stmt*>` in a transform pass ? Thanks.